# .txt file is empty after writing from python script --/-- passing decryption key

Tags: python, encryption, blowfish

I'm trying to create a script for appending/changing/retrieving passwords from a .txt file acting as a password manager.

When researching the history of the question being asked here, it seems the issue for most users is that they forget to `flush()` or `close()` their file stream.

```
theList = {}

# Populates theList with pairs
def getData():
    with open('pass_data.txt', 'w+') as data:
        for line in data:
            keyValuePair = line.split()
            theList[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1]

# Writes pairs from theList to file 'pass_data.txt'
def putData():
    with open('pass_data.txt', 'w+') as data:
        for k, v in theList.items():
            data.writelines([k, ' ', v, "\n"])
        data.flush()

# Appends new pair to theList or overwrites if already exists
def setPass(service, password):
    getData()
    theList[service] = password
    putData()

# Retrieves password from given key 'service'
def getPass(service):
    getData()
    print theList[service]
```

I added `flush()` after reading up on the issue and it makes no difference...my .txt is still empty and I can't `getPass('service')` when calling the function from the command line because it says there is no key value 'service'.

---

I have a second question that someone may be able to answer for me here as well. If I encrypt the pass_data.txt file with blowfish from vim `vim -u ~/.vimrc_encrypted -x pass_data.txt`, is there a way I can pass the key for decrypting the file as an argument for `setPass()` and `getPass()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open):

> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and
>   writing); note that 'w+' truncates the file. Append 'b' to the mode to
>   open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between
>   binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction,
>   adding the 'b' has no effect.

In `getData` you are basically truncating your file before reading it, thus it appears empty.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

This solves my problem, but for the sake of visibility for the second question, I'll leave this marked as unsolved for a few hours.